Should I `std::move` from the `std::future`?
Let's say I have a function that returns a std::vector, and I want to call it asynchronously.
std::vector<int> foo(int n);

int main() {
    auto future_vector = std::async(foo, 999);
    // ... other stuff

    // Questions are all about this:
    auto actual_vector = future_vector.get();

    // ... do stuff with actual_vector ...
}

Q1:  Is actual_vector copy-constructed or move-constructed from the shared state?  Do I need to write std::move(future_vector.get()) explicitly?
Q2:  Assuming the function completed and no longer holds the promise:  Does the shared state's lifetime end when get is called on the future or does it persist until the future reaches the end of its lifetime?

actual_vector will be allocated by the caller (and most likely) the data will be moved into it by get since it is not allowed to call get twice.(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get), in any case you will be owner of the data after the return. The section that is relevant : The get member function waits (by calling wait()) until the shared state is ready, then retrieves the value stored in the shared state (if any). Right after calling this function, valid() is false. (So after calling get the future is no longer in a valid state)

@PepijnKramer:  Thanks, I've been studying that cppreference page for a while. I understand that you can call get only once and after that the future is no longer valid. But that doesn't tell me when the shared state object's destruction happens.

std::future::get returns by-value (except in the specialization for reference types). Calling move on a a function returning by value is always wrong. In fact, giving any argument that doesn't just name a (member) variable to std::move is almost always wrong.
The constructor call used to construct actual_vector is completely up to the implementation of get. However, the standard mandates that the value is produced as if by call std::move(v) where v is the shared state, so move construction will be used if possible.

std::future::get is also specified to release the shared state, i.e. it must destroy the object in the shared state if the std::future is the last object referencing the shared state.

My question about the lifetime of the shared state was motivated by the timing of destruction.  Imagine the shared state object contained a std::shared_ptr and calling get resulted in a copy rather than a move.  In that case, you might care when the shared state's destructor runs so that you can ensure the pointed-to object doesn't hang around longer than necessary.

@AdrianMcCarthy That's not usually a problem. Moving from the object should cause the shared pointer to be left empty.

@AdrianMcCarthy Also I got confused. I looked it up again and get will always destroy the shared state. I mixed that up with some slightly different question.
